# How to do facebook API login using anchor tag link using Javascript function? give URL which is use in <a href="?"></a> for facebook API login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, facebook

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=http://www.cocreatorclub.com/login">
            <img src="<?php echo ASSETS;?>images/facebook01.png" width="27" height="27"  alt=""/>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Above URL is not working.

Comment: <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?&
  client_id=1785540421679243
  &redirect_uri=http://www.cocreatorclub.com/login"><img src="<?php echo ASSETS;?>images/facebook01.png" width="27" height="27"  alt=""/></a></li> ......this is updated url... thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to include the new url

Comment: below button code which is working but i want to change it with backgound image in anchor  <li><fb:login-button style="margin-top:8%" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button></li>

Answer (score 2):

Change the `?&client_id` to `?client_id`

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=....&redirect_uri=http://www.cocreatorclub.com/login">
            <img src="<?php echo ASSETS;?>images/facebook01.png" width="27" height="27"  alt=""/>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Having seen your comments I must confess I'm a little confused. Do you wish to replace the href attribute in the `a` tag and utilise javascript instead?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id='fbl'>
            <img src="<?php echo ASSETS;?>images/facebook01.png" width="27" height="27"  alt=""/>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
    document.getElementById('fbl').addEventListener('click',checkLoginState,false);
</script>
```

Comment: It gives error Moved temporarily(302)

Comment: Thanks for reply Ram

Comment: How to replace href="#" url by using javascript function for "onlogin" in facebook login API

Comment: <li><fb:login-button style="margin-top:8%" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button></li>                      this is working... but i want to replace it with anchor tag by using href="#" or javascript function call

Comment: onlogin="checkLoginState();" how to replace this with javascript function call for "onlogin" or with anchor

Comment: it gives error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null statusChangeCallback
Object {status: "unknown", authResponse: null}